# nginx $http_upgrade in openresty access_by_lua_block

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

what is the name or how ca I call $http_upgrade of NGINX in OPENRESTY access_by_lua_block

so I can use it here

```
access_by_lua_block {
   ???
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either [ngx.var.VARIABLE](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxvarvariable) or [ngx.req.get_headers](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqget_headers) API to get a value of any request header:

```
access_by_lua_block {
    ngx.log(ngx.INFO, ngx.var.http_upgrade)
    ngx.log(ngx.INFO, ngx.req.get_headers()['upgrade'])
}
```

From the documentation:

> Note that the [ngx.var.HEADER](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxvarvariable) API call, which uses core [$http_HEADER](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) variables, may be more preferable for reading individual request headers.